# Convert origin of UICollectionViewCell to ViewController's frame

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, frame, uicollectionview

When a user selects a collectionView cell, I animate that cell's frame to grow and reposition so that it is sitting has this size/location:

```
CGRectMake(114, 148, 540, 620)
```

This works well if I haven't scrolled down to other cells in the collectionView. When I try this on a lower cell, it still animates, but the cell goes shooting up so that it's y coordinate can be at 148 for the collectionView.

I have tried all sorts of variants of convertRect and convertPoint, but I am unable to conceptualize the correct solution.

What do I need to do to convert the selected cell's y value to move to the equivalent of 148 in the superview's coordinate system?

EDIT: To reduce confusion

I tap on a cell at the bottom (meaning I scroll down several rows) of my collectionView and this is the origin:

```
(x=394.5, y=4114)
```

The x here is fine, but I have a problem with the y. I want to animate this cell that I just selected so that it appears as though it's y coordinate is at 148 of the outer view. Just like a form sheet modal view controller. But setting that origin to 148 causes the cell to fly up to the top of the collectionView because it is all the way down at 4114. How can I get the correct y value that looks like 148 to the user, but in reality will be something closer to the cell's original origin?

EDIT 2: PIC

[image]

Comment: Where are you setting the frames cell?

Comment: Inside of 'didSelectItemAtIndexPath'

Comment: and didSelectItemAtIndexPath is getting called everytime you scroll?

Comment: yes, but due to the fact that the collectionView has scrolled, the y coordinate of the cell is like 4300. And to set that to 148 causes it to go all the way up to the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to do then the solution is simple: the "y" position of your cell should be `self.collectionView.contentOffset.y + 148`.

```
CGRectMake(114, self.collectionView.contentOffset.y + 148, 540, 620);
```

This will work with any given scroll value.

Hope this helps!